# Asymptotic behavior of two functions

Tags: asymptotics

I have trouble figuring out the asymptotic behavior of two functions.

1. If $f(n) = n \log n$, then what do we know about $f^{-1}(n)$? I.e. what is the asymptotic behavior of $g(n)$ such that $g(n) \log(g(n)) = \Theta(n)$, perhaps in terms of some familiar functions?
2. Behavior of $n^{\frac{1}{\log \log n}}$. I know that $n^{\frac{1}{\log n}} = e$, so this function would be super-constant. But what is known about its asymptotic behavior?

Comment: By asymptotic behavior, do you want to find a function that is ~ to $f$?

Comment: $n^{\frac{1}{\ln(n)}} = e$ if and only if $n > 0$, actually. Anyway, you can always try some technique like the approximation

$$\ln(n!) \approx n\ln(n) - n$$ and manipulate to see if you can pull out the rabbit!

Comment: @GregoryGrant Yes, or if that is too strict then possible upper and lower bounds.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve these problems by **iterating for several steps**. To make my point clear, I'll show you an example.

Now I try to determine the large roots of the equation
$$x\tan x=1,\ x>0.$$
Inversion produces
$$x=n\pi+\arctan \frac{1}{x},\tag{1}$$
where $n$ is an integer and the inverse tangent has its principal value which is bounded. So
$$x\sim n\pi,\ n\to \infty.$$
Next, when $x>1$, the expansion
$$\arctan x^{-1}=\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{3x^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^5}\right)$$
shows that
$$x-n\pi=\arctan x^{-1}=O(x^{-1})=O(n^{-1}).$$
By the formula (1), one can get
\begin{align*}
x& =n\pi+\frac{1}{x}+O(x^{-3})\\
& =n\pi+\frac{1}{n\pi+O(n^{-1})}+O(n^{-3})\\
& =n\pi+\frac{1}{n\pi}+O(n^{-3}).
\end{align*}
The next substitution produces
$$x=n\pi+\frac{1}{n\pi}-\frac{4}{3\left(n\pi\right)^3}+O(n^{-3}).$$